# Include errors with clang-tidy, CMake, Ninja, MinGW and Visual Studio on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, mingw, clang-tidy

When compiling the following Hello World project in Visual Studio with MinGW toolchain using Ninja, `iostream` cannot be found by clang-tidy.

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(my_project)
add_executable(my_project main.cpp)
find_program(clang_tidy_EXECUTABLE NAMES clang-tidy REQUIRED)
set_target_properties(my_project PROPERTIES CXX_CLANG_TIDY "${clang_tidy_EXECUTABLE}")
```

`main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() { std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl; return 0; }
```

In "CMake Settings" within Visual Studio, "Mingw64-Debug" profile is selected.

Clang-tidy should be able to find `iostream` when compiling, but it gives the following error:

```
error GA720FDDA: 'iostream' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]
  #include <iostream>
           ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Compiling with CLion, using a different compiler (clang-cl) or disabling clang-tidy (removing last line in CMakeLists.txt) fixes the problem. Problem persists across different PCs. What could be its cause?

Comment: I also ran into the same issue on Linux using `clang-tidy-14.0.6`, found this cmake workaround: `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})` here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20912#note_793338

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same issue on Linux using `clang-tidy` 14.0.6.

It seems that `clang-tidy` is not able to detect the system header include path.

Found this cmake [workaround](//gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20912#note_793338):

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})
```

Which adds the `-isystem` argument to every compiler command and `clang-tidy` then picks it up.

**Update:**

I just fixed my machine by `sudo apt install libstdc++-13-dev`.

The whole `clang`/`llvm` toolset (not just `clang-tidy`) was missing the `stdc++` headers on my computer after a minor upgrade (`clang-14.0.0` to `clang-14.0.6` I think), so the whole compiler `clang` toolset was useless.

The actual change that broke it on my Debian installation was that `gcc-13` got released and `clang-14` somehow got configured to use `libstdc++-13`, but this was not installed on my computer (the default compiler is `gcc-12` so I have `libstdc++-12`). Basically it was a Debian package missing this dependency.

Perhaps something similar is happening with MinGW.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll give this a test within the week.